# Getting empty contact us email

Tags: bigcommerce

From `web pages`, I have created one form using "Allow people to send questions/comments via a contact form" but when i submit form, it is showing nothing in `email` means only `labels` and no data entered by users.

When user submit information from contact form then why it shows nothing in email as you can see following image showing issue.

[image]

What can be the issue and how I can solve it?

Comment: I down voted this because you have no request in your post.  Consider showing your form code in an example as you have it.  Also, it would be nice to know a direct task to perform to resolve your issue.  Do you want the form to refuse blank entries, do you expect entries and you're getting none?  Your actual issue is not well defined.

Comment: No it does not, please Read here.(http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) You need to show the code where you are having this error occur. Give an example of what you've attempted to fix the issue.  If you haven't tried anything to fix it that's okay but generally speaking it's favored when you have tried a few fixes before posting questions.  That said, go to (http://jsfiddle.net/) and copy your relevant code into the HTML, CSS, and JS input windows. Press "RUN" to make sure it's executing as you expected. Then press "save" and post the new URL generated in your question.